# I don't see the cookie in Spring Boot from React

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot backend I have a JwtService which sets a cookie with a refresh token.

```
private void addJwtCookie(HttpServletResponse response, String refreshToken) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("jwt", refreshToken);
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    cookie.setMaxAge((int) refreshTokenExpiration);
    cookie.setSecure(true);
    // This has to be set to work for all endpoints
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

My cors configuration is the following:

```
 @Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Content-Type"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

From React I make the call like so:

```
const signIn = async (signInRequest: SignInRequest) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/v1/auth/sign-in`,
                                    signInRequest, { withCredentials: true })
        setUser(res.data)
    } catch (err) {
    }
}

const refresh = async () => {
    const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/v1/auth/refresh-token`,
                                  { withCredentials: true })
    if (res.data) {
        setUser(res.data)
    }
}
```

First I call signIn, then I can find the Cookie in Chrome Devtools.
[image]

But in the refreshToken method in Spring Boot Cookies array is empty.

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

How can I send the cookie from React? The magic is in AuthService.
repo: https://github.com/dimitar557/reddit/tree/backend

Comment: What is the value of `process.env.REACT_APP_API` ?

Comment: REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:8080, the signIn request works.

Comment: I've not played with these techs too much (esp. SpringBoot), but is it that your URL to axios() is not specifying a scheme (in particular `http://`) and so is using something else (e.g. `https://`) but your SpringBoot is set to `cookie.setHttpOnly(true);` ?

Comment: REACT_APP_API=http:// localhost:8080, it has http:// stack overflow removed the http because it is site.

Comment: the cookie wont get sent if you are not doing requests using https, the `secure` flag set means that the browser will refuse to send the cookie unless TLS is used.

Comment: Makes no difference if it's secure or not, I have gotten these same cookies to work with node js before. They work with http and as you can see in the photo I received the cookie. With Spring I can't make it to work and I couldn't find any resource to make it work. I'm thinking is something to do with the server side.

Comment: No, I'm trying to make it work.